Control Panel: Performance after update vom Craft 4 to Craft 5 (Neo)
I’m a heavy Neo user, and my “content builder” is a Neo field with about 40 (sub-)block types. Overall, I’m using 116 fields in my project, which is a boilerplate for other projects.
With Craft 4.12.x and Neo 4.2.x, I was very satisfied with the performance in the control panel as well as on the frontend (website).
However, after updating to Craft 5.4.x and Neo 5.2.x, the performance of the control panel has slowed down dramatically (on my local DDEV environment), and on my hosting (shared webspace), it’s become completely unusable due to PHP out-of-memory errors.
If I had developed something custom, I wouldn’t be asking for help, but I’m simply using the control panel as provided, out of the box.
In the attached screenshot, you can see a comparison of the debug toolbar between Craft 4 and Craft 5 with the same entry and identical content. The Neo configuration remained unchanged, but the result shows that events, logs, memory usage, and database queries have increased significantly.
I’ve already disabled other plugins, but that didn’t result in any noticeable improvement. When I remove the “content builder” (Neo field), everything works fine again, which leads me to believe the issue is related to Neo. However, since Neo utilizes Craft core functions under the hood, it could potentially be a Craft issue as well—I’m not sure.
Given this problem, I’m hesitant to upgrade to Craft 5 because I’d lose a lot of flexibility in content creation. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue, or am I the only one facing problems with such a (possibly too?) complex configuration?
I’ve discussed this issue here on GitHub: https://github.com/spicywebau/craft-neo/issues/950
Let me know if you need any further adjustments!
Screenshot , comparison of Craft 4 and Craft 5:



Fixed now within this Neo update: https://github.com/spicywebau/craft-neo/tree/5.2.12

Would eager loading be a solution?
https://craftcms.com/docs/5.x/development/eager-loading.html

If this were about the frontend (website), my first choice would definitely be eager loading.
However, I’m specifically talking about the control panel, straight out of the box.
